# Can't control my radio/checkbox margins the way I like

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

I'v got 3 id's - `#gender` (radio), `#frequent` (also radio), `#player` (checkbox)

1. I want to make my space between my inputs to my labels to be 16px (for example)
2. I want to make my #frequent and #player id's to go into two lines.

I'v tried to give to my #gender 20% width to the label and 80% to the input (and I'v played around it) and nothing.

And the `#frequent` act like a column all though I'v tried to give it flex-direction: row;

This is my Codepen and part of my code:
for the gender,

```
<div id="gender">
  <label for="male"> Male  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" />

  <label for="female"> Female </label>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" />
</div>
```

and

```
#gender{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#gender label {
  width: 20%;
}
#gender input[type="radio"]{
  width: 80%;
}
```

For the frequent,

```
<div id="frequent">
  <legend> How Frequent Do You Listen To Music </legend>
  <label for="aday">All day </label>
  <input type="radio" id="aday" name="frequent"/>

  <label for="eday">Every day</label>
  <input type="radio" id="eday" name="frequent"/>

  <label for="oday">Every other day</label>
  <input type="radio" id="oday" name="frequent"/>

  <label for="party">I'm a party person</label>
  <input type="radio" id="party" name="frequent"/>
</div>
```

And

```
#frequent {
  display: flex;
}
#frequent legend {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
#frequent label {
  width: 20%;
}
#frequent input[type="radio"]{
  width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: You need to set flex-wrap:wrap

Comment: I have tried it and it didn't work, still my #gender input is to far from the input and the #frequent & #player input is not in a straight line and to close to the label

Comment: From your description is not clear, how is that different from:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F1pQ.jpg ?

Comment: So maybe it will be easier to break into pieces... I want to narrow down the space between my #gender label and the input, how can I do that?

Comment: Ok, and what are you trying to get by using display: flex? I'm interested because here https://codepen.io/Yulia_pi/pen/KRrqmO, without all your styles and negative margins to input fields it looks similar to  your description (different rows)